# Coldfusion 9.0.1 hotfix 4 Object Instantiation Exception. Class not found: coldfusion.security.ESAPIUtils

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, hotfix

I updated my CF 9.0.1 server with CHF 4. I had upgraded Java to 7 just prior to that and couldn't restart the CF service.  I find a lot of items on the problem but not a solution.  Correction; the only solution is to back out the hotfix.  I've verified that I did the hotfix according to instructions.  All of the sites seem to work but I can't start CF Admin.

Comment: You may have already seen this article, but if not it might help track down the problem: [CF911: Are you finding CF (or CF Admin) busted after applying a hotfix? A few possible reasons](http://carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2011/10/21/why_chfs_may_break).

Comment: Yes I saw it.  But as I said, there's no solution but to back out the hotfix.

Comment: Can I go up to 9.0.2?